# geogrid.exe: error while loading shared libraries: libnetcdf.so.18: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: netcdf

I would like to ask if the error in the title is related to netcdf, netcdf-c or netcdf-fortran library. I am trying to run the system of WPS and WRF. I work in a cluster and netcdf-c is not available for gcc/8.2.0 and openmpi/3.1.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That library gets created when compiling netcdf-c.

I'm pretty sure the CentOS/Redhat RPMs do include libnetcdf and they are compiled with gcc

If the library is not in a standard path, your binary may not find in unless you tell it where to find it with LD_LIBRARY_PATH

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/path/to/custom/netcdf/lib:${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}"
```

Comment: Thanks, tecnico in my cluster netcdf-c is not available for this combination, thus i only loaded netcdf and netcdf-fortran. Thus, i have to change the compiler to intel or to a newer version of gcc and openmpi.